# meteor up deployment error:

Tags: javascript, meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

while trying to deploy my app using mup deploy, I got the following logs:

> -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
>
> Warning: Permanently added '128.xxx.xxx.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> : Not a directorye 6: cd: ./Icon

I have successfully used mup deploy to deploy the same project before. I have even tried mup deploy with other previous projects and this error is still showing up. Has anyone encounter this and can share how to tackle this? I can't debug this as this doesn't even have a proper message output.

Please kindly help :(

Thanks and regards.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post the results of `mup logs -n 200`

Comment: not much insightful stuff in the mup logs....all are the console log stuff from my app that is deployed in DigitalOcean previously...